# Manipulating data set using R

Tags: r, sorting, dataset, data-manipulation

I have a bundle of data .txt datasets, some of them go like this,

```
1.0
DOO
SB009101V 222429.80 2588228.00
12
GR 1 LIN
CALI 1 LIN
NPHI 1 LIN
PHIE 1 LIN
RHOB 1 LIN
DT 1 LIN
K_AIR 2 LOG
KLINK_PERM 1 LIN
GRAIN_DENSITY 1 LIN
POR 1 LIN
Core disc 0 No 1 Yes
Perforation disc 0 No 1 Yes
  222444.7  2588243.0  7381.00   -999.000     11.320   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000     0     0
```

Although this shows two lines of data it is actually one line only, first three numbers indicate X,Y,Z respectively, the other data corresponds to GR CALI NPHI PHIE RHOB DT K_AIR KLINK_PERM GRAIN_DENSITY POR Core Perforation respectively.

I want a code in R that converts the above data into something like this

```
Xcoord Ycoord Zcoord GR CALI NPHI PHIE RHOB DT K_AIR KLINK_PERM GRAIN_DENSITY POR Core Perforation
  222444.7  2588243.0  7381.00   -999.000     11.320   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000   -999.000     0     0
```

ignoring the first 4 lines of data, also some data sets have missing column names of CALI, K_AIR etc is there anyway to make a column for them and insert NA as values till n=nrow?

I have so far managed to edit them manually in excel and then manipulate the data by subsetting as required but i have over 400 data sets to work with. Any help/ direction?

Regards
Shiva

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=nevlmr&s=8#.U-Sg2fmSx9k

Comment: use `skip from ?read.table`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
files <- list.files(path = "path/to/data/folder", pattern = ".dat", full.names = TRUE)
data <- lapply(files, read.table, skip = 16, col.names = c("Xcoord", "Ycoord", "Zcoord", "GR", "CALI", "NPHI", "PHIE", "RHOB", "DT", "K_AIR", "KLINK_PERM", "GRAIN_DENSITY", "POR", "Core", "Perforation"))
```

I think you can wrap an unlist around lapply to merge it to a single data frame.

Comment: Not all files have 16 lines of vertical rows, so skip = 16 is not dynamic enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you have probably posted this question again, and in a different format. This is a public forum, and people are happy to help. However, it's your job to simplify life of others, and you are requested to put in some effort. [Here is some advice on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Having said that, here is some code I have written to help you out.

**Step0:** Creating your first data set:

```
sink("test.txt")  # This will `sink` all the output to the file "test.txt"

# Lets start with some dummy data
cat("1\n")
cat("DOO\n")
cat(c(sample(letters,10),"\n"))
cat(c(sample(letters,10),"\n"))
cat(c(sample(letters,10),"\n"))
cat(c(sample(letters,10),"\n"))

# Now a 10 x 16 dummy data matrix:
cat(paste(apply(matrix(sample(160),10),1,paste,collapse = "\t"),collapse = "\n"))
cat("\n")

sink()            # This will stop `sink`ing.
```

I have created some dummy data in first 6 lines, and followed by a 10 x 16 data matrix.

Note: In principle you should have provided something like this, or a copy of your dataset. This would help other people help you.

**Step1**: Now we need to read the file, and we want to skip the first 6 rows with undesired info:

```
(temp <- read.table(file="test.txt", sep ="\t", skip = 6))
```

**Step2**: Data clean up:
We need a vector with names of the 16 columns in our data:

```
namesVec <- letters[1:16]
```

Now we assign these names to our data.frame:

```
names(temp) <- namesVec
temp
```

Looks good!

**Step3**: Save the data:

```
write.table(temp,file="test-clean.txt",row.names = FALSE,sep = "\t",quote = FALSE)
```

Check if the solution is working. If it is working, than move to next step, otherwise make necessary changes.

**Step4**: Automating:

First we need to create a list of all the 400 files.
The easiest way (to explain also) is copy the 400 files in a directory, and then set that as working directory (using `setwd`).

Now first we'll create a vector with all file names:

```
fileNameList <- dir()
```

Once this is done, we'll need to function to repeat step 1 through 3:

```
convertFiles <- function(fileName) {
  temp <- read.table(file=fileName, sep ="\t", skip = 6)
  names(temp) <- namesVec  
  write.table(temp,file=paste("clean","test.txt",sep="-"),row.names = FALSE,sep = "\t",quote = FALSE)
}
```

Now we simply need to apply this function on all the files we have:

```
sapply(fileNameList,convertFiles)
```

Hope this helps!